# Using sed to replace only first ocurrence while using variable and "/" in variable

Tags: bash, sed

I have a file that looks like this

```
I/am/a/string
I'm/still/a/string
Always/a/string
```

I'm trying to use sed to replace the first occurrence of "string" with a variable that contains "/" like

```
x=ive/been/replaced
```

So the output of sed would be

```
I/am/a/ive/been/replaced
```

Because i only want the first occurrence and i'm using a variable typically you use

```
sed -i "0,/string/s//$x/" file
```

However in this case because the variable has "/" i have to use a different separator like

```
sed "0,|string|s||$x|" file
```

But this does not work.

what am i missing?

NOTE:

I would like to accomplish this in sed

Comment: Do you want `string` to be treated as a literal string or as a regular expression with additional limitations on chars it can contain? Do you want a solution that works for any `x` or only works when `x` contains some subset of characters? If you want a solution that treats `string` as a regexp with additional limitations and only works if `x` doesn't contain some characters then you are on the right track by wanting to do this in sed. If/when you want it to work for literal strings of any characters, let us know and we can provide an awk solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are ok using `awk`: you can print and exit after first replacement.

```
awk -v x="${x}" '{gsub(/string/,x);print ;exit}' file
I/am/a/ive/been/replaced
```

`sed` version: This will exit after first match, note that search string "string" is still inside `/ /` whereas substitution part is using different separator.

```
sed -n   "0,/string/ s|string|$x|p"   
I/am/a/ive/been/replaced
```

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using awk sed would be shorter and more straight to the point. If its not possible i understand but beyond that this will eat me alive.